# wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) redis catch store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

When I start rails server locally (rails 6.1.3.2, ruby 3.0.0) with this configuration in develompent.rb

```
  config.active_record.cache_versioning = false
  config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://localhost:6379/0/cache"
```

with gem redis-rails '5.0.2' installed

I've this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:785:in `initialize'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/redis-activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:85:in `new'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/redis-activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:85:in `block in write'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:724:in `block in instrument'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:724:in `instrument'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/redis-activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:81:in `write'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:754:in `save_block_result_to_cache'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@cync-auth-rails-6/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:339
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the redis-rails readme](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails#a-quick-note-about-rails-52): Rails itself has had a redis store since 5.2 (and consequently, redis-rails hasn't been tested beyond Rail 5). [Just use `RedisCacheStore`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-rediscachestore)